# The route helper generates the wrong URL when using Route attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller where I use route attributes, see below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/hello/product")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{

    [Route("productId:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetProduct(int productId)
    {}

}
```

In my view I have this:

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl(new { area="hello", controller = "Product", action = "GetProduct", productId = 123 })';

console.log(url);
```

The output is:

```
/hello/product/GetProduct?userId=123
```

When it should have been:

```
/api/hello/product/123
```

Is this a bug or does Url.Route just not work when you use Route attributes?

Comment: Well, for one you have some unclosed quotation marks in your RoutePrefixes, but I don't know if that's the issue. Additionally, shouldn't ProductController inherit from BaseController instead of itself?

Comment: @C.Helling sorry that was just a typo

Comment: Also e.g. `[Route("productId:int}")]` should be something like `[Route("{productId:int}")]`. I just want to make sure your error isn't simply typographical.

Comment: Can you also post your RouteConfig?